# How to load a component without a page reload on ion-button click?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

I have a button on the homepage of my application:

`<ion-button href="/start" class="btn" color="danger">start</ion-button>`

However, I noticed it actually reloads the page when clicked.

I also have ionic tabs (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs), and when a tab is clicked a component is loaded instantly.

How can I achieve the same functionality for ion-button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab component has an integration with the router, which allows the tab to function as a vue-router link. `ion-button` doesn't seem to have the same integration. The documentation for the `href` prop states:

`Contains a URL or a URL fragment that the hyperlink points to. If this property is set, an anchor tag will be rendered.`

Using `href` makes the button function as a regular browser link which will cause the page to reload. Instead, you can wrap the `ion-button` in a `router-link` tag or call `$router.push` in the button's `click` event.